# delete substring inside column between two delimeter

Tags: mysql

I have an inherited mysql db with a lot of junk data like:

```
<span class="editContent" data-key="services_pan6" >EDIT</span>'> My real text </span>
```

and I should delete the special tags to remaining just 'My real text'.

But I can't find any solution to it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: How can you identify the real text?  Why does your example have `</span>` twice?

Comment: It's a copied text from the database. the data-key is different in every record, and the text what I need is between the two '>' '<' character

Comment: A solution could be to write a php (or other language) script to parse all data and extract your value with a regex and update the target row.

Comment: That what I think too, but I hoped you can help me with it.

Comment: @LászlóNyúzó . . . In your example, the word "Edit" is between those characters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is a (very, too much) dirty solution that can help you to export the real text you need from your database:

SELECT TRIM("'>" FROM TRIM( "" FROM SUBSTRING(field_name, LOCATE("", field_name) , LOCATE("", field_name, 2)))) FROM table_name;

Just replace "table_name" and "field_name".

Answer (score 0):

you can define a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION strSplit(x varchar(255), delim varchar(12), pos int) returns varchar(255)
return replace(substring(substring_index(x, delim, pos), length(substring_index(x, delim, pos - 1)) + 1), delim, '');
```

and then use it to split your string until you reach your desired text.
for example :

```
select strSplit("a#b", '#',1) as first; -> aaa
select strSplit("aaa,b,cc,d", ',', 2) as second; -> b
```